# Evaluate Dax expression at leaf level then sum up the results

Tags: sql, sql-server, dax, ssas-tabular

I am trying to essentially mimic the behaviour of performing a T-SQL calculation inside a subquery and summing up the results of that calculation in an outer query,  within DAX.

At the leaf level I have the following simple calculation:

```
ROUND((SUMX('Profile Category Views',  'Profile Category Views'[Visit]) * 1.52 ) , 0)
```

For each row `'Profile Category Views'[Visit] = 1`.

This calculation is correct at the leaf level, however when i aggregate the results of the sum, the calculation is applied at run time, at a higher level, skewing the results.

[image: Example]

As shown in the image above - the calculation has been applied to the detail row.  However the Grand total = 43, which shows the calculation has been applied again after summing the raw total of the detail rows, rather than the sum of all of the detail rows after the initial calculation has been applied which would = 44.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum the rounded totals, but still also round the overall total, something like

```
(SUMX('Profile Category Views',  ROUND('Profile Category Views'[Visit] * 1.52,0) ))
```

i.e., round the detail at the lowest level.

Comment: The outer `ROUND` seems redundant here.

Comment: Its not a case of double rounding. I only need the rounding to apply at the lowest level, once the calculation and rounding has been applied,I would like to sum up the values to get a total.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ugly, but this might work for you:

```
= SUMX(VALUES('Profile Category Views'[Geography]),
       ROUND(
           SUMX(
               FILTER('Profile Category Views',
                   'Profile Category Views'[Geography] = EARLIER('Profile Category Views'[Geography])),
               'Profile Category Views'[Visit] * 1.52)
          ,0))
```

For each `[Geography]` value we take the subtotal and round it. (The `FILTER` is to make sure the inner `SUMX` adds up each `[Geography]` value one at a time. `EARLIER` will return the filter context from the outer `SUMX`, i.e., the current `[Geography]` value.)

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately - gave me a very large total?

Comment: It's hard to debug without being able to see all the context, but it might be summing over all of the `[Category]` values as well. You should probably include that in the filter as well.